# Ledger XMR Balance 0 but Monero GUI Wallet Balance is >0

Tags: ledger

Have installed latest version of Monero on Windows and performed following;

1. Created wallet from hardware (Ledger Nano S)
2. Synchronised deacon
3. Balance now showing correctly from a previous transaction of Monero from Binance

However, my ledger Monero app is showing XMR = 0.
Is this correct or am I doing something wrong
Thanks loads

Comment: It is expected that the Ledger Monero App on the device does not show the correct balance.

Comment: Getting the same issue, did you find an answer?